# thymeleaf: Text and icons in the same TD

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf, font-awesome

I want to put in the same cell of a table Text & Icons, like this, but it seems that it does not work because only the text appears

```
<td class="col_name" th:text="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality}" >GOOD
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'EXCELLENT'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#009933; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'GOOD'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#0066cc; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'AVERAGE'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#ff9900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'LIMIT'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#ff5050; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
</td><!-- NAME -->
```

Comment: Are you sure you re including the font awesome library?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in another part of the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `th:text` will replace all children nodes, in this case also the markup for the icons. The solution is to add a dedicated `span` for the text part:

```xml
<td class="col_name">
  <span th:text="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality}">GOOD</span>
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'EXCELLENT'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#009933; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
  <span th:if="${mareSuperiora.linkQuality == 'GOOD'}" >                                                     
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x" style="color:#0066cc; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                           
  </span>
  <!-- and so on -->
</td>
```